# Override the forward-key on WP7-Keyboard

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, overriding, forward

How can I override the event of the forward-arrow, which is on virtual keyboar on a windows phone device?

I'd like to use it for a method.

Comment: But Key.Enter is not the forward key on the visual keyboard.

Comment: The "forward" key displays on the virtual keyboard with input type of "search". I have not personally verified whether that key maps to Key.Enter or not.  Per the other thread, it sounds like it does. You can put in a handler for KeyUp as described and debug to see what key is returned when you press the "forward" key.